# VSCode unable to use "Spring Boot: Manage Live Spring Boot Process Connections"

Tags: spring-tools-4

I started debugging my Spring Boot 2.7.3 app in my VSCode and try to use "Spring Boot: Manage Live Spring Boot Process Connections" feature.

[image]

I believe I choose the right Process ID:

[image]

The VSCode always show up "Refreshing data from Spring process: 7748 - retry no: 3"

[image]

I always get the following error:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-requisite for this feature to work is that your Spring Boot project has the Spring Boot Actuator Starter module as a dependency. If not, there is no way for the tooling to get the live information from the running application.

Once you have that, the necessary startup options will be set automatically when launching your application and the live information will appear in your source code as well as inside of the views of the Spring Boot Dashboard (in case you have that extension installed as well).

If that doesn't work, please open an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach a sample project to reproduce the issue.